# implement a multiset/bag as Scala collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections, multiset

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617024/are-multisets-missing-in-scala), I'd like to implement a [Multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset_%28abstract_data_type%29#Multiset) in Scala. I'd like a `MultiSet[A]` to:

- Support adding, removing, union, intersection and difference
- Be an `A => Int`, providing the count of each element

Here's one approach, extending `Set`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
import scala.collection.immutable.Set
import scala.collection.SetLike
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder

class MultiSet[A](private val counts: Map[A, Int] = Map.empty[A, Int])
extends SetLike[A, MultiSet[A]] with Set[A] {
  override def +(elem: A): MultiSet[A] = {
    val count = this.counts.getOrElse(elem, 0) + 1
    new MultiSet(this.counts + (elem -> count)) 
  }
  override def -(elem: A): MultiSet[A] = this.counts.get(elem) match {
    case None => this
    case Some(1) => new MultiSet(this.counts - elem)
    case Some(n) => new MultiSet(this.counts + (elem -> (n - 1)))
  }
  override def contains(elem: A): Boolean = this.counts.contains(elem)
  override def empty: MultiSet[A] = new MultiSet[A]
  override def iterator: Iterator[A] = {
    for ((elem, count) <- this.counts.iterator; _ <- 1 to count) yield elem
  }
  override def newBuilder: Builder[A,MultiSet[A]] = new Builder[A, MultiSet[A]] {
    var multiSet = empty
    def +=(elem: A): this.type = {this.multiSet += elem; this}
    def clear(): Unit = this.multiSet = empty
    def result(): MultiSet[A] = this.multiSet
  }
  override def seq: MultiSet[A] = this
}

object MultiSet {
  def empty[A]: MultiSet[A] = new MultiSet[A]
  def apply[A](elem: A, elems: A*): MultiSet[A] = MultiSet.empty + elem ++ elems
  def apply[A](elems: Seq[A]): MultiSet[A] = MultiSet.empty ++ elems
  def apply[A](elem: (A, Int), elems: (A, Int)*) = new MultiSet((elem +: elems).toMap)
  def apply[A](elems: Map[A, Int]): MultiSet[A] = new MultiSet(elems)
}
```

Extending `Set` is nice, because it means that `MultiSet` automatically gets definitions for union, difference, etc. All the following will hold:

```
// add
assert(
  MultiSet("X" -> 3, "Y" -> 1) + "X" ===
    MultiSet("X" -> 4, "Y" -> 1))
assert(
  MultiSet("X" -> 3, "Y" -> 1) + "Z" ===
    MultiSet("X" -> 3, "Y" -> 1, "Z" -> 1))

// remove
assert(
  MultiSet("a" -> 2, "b" -> 5) - "b" ===
    MultiSet("a" -> 2, "b" -> 4))
assert(
  MultiSet("a" -> 2, "b" -> 5) - "c" ===
    MultiSet("a" -> 2, "b" -> 5))

// add all
assert(
  MultiSet(10 -> 1, 100 -> 3) ++ MultiSet(10 -> 1, 1 -> 7) ===
    MultiSet(100 -> 3, 10 -> 2, 1 -> 7))

// remove all
assert(
  MultiSet("a" -> 2, "b" -> 5) -- MultiSet("a" -> 3) ===
    MultiSet("b" -> 5))
```

However, I would have to override some inherited methods like `union` and `intersect` because they would do the wrong things for multisets, e.g. the following would not hold:

```
// union (takes max of values)
assert(
  MultiSet(10 -> 5, 1 -> 1).union(MultiSet(10 -> 3, 1 -> 7)) ===
    MultiSet(10 -> 5, 1 -> 7))

// intersection (takes min of values)
assert(
  MultiSet(10 -> 5, 100 -> 3).intersect(MultiSet(10 -> 1, 1 -> 7)) ===
    MultiSet(10 -> 1))
```

Another problem with extending `Set` is that then I can't have `MultiSet` be an `A => Int` because I'll get the error: `illegal inheritance;  class MultiSet inherits different type instances of trait Function1: A => Int and A => Boolean`. I could work around this by declaring a separate, say, `count` method, but I'd really prefer that the class just be an `A => Int`.

Another approach would be to inherit from `Map[A, Int]`, which would give me the `A => Int` that I want, but then I would have to define all of my own `++`, `--`, etc. since in `Map` these would be defined over `(A, Int)` pairs, but for a multiset they need to be defined over  `A`s.

I guess a third approach would be to give up on both `Set` and `Map`, and just implement a new subclass of `Iterable` or whatever.

What would you recommend? What's the best way to fit a `MulitSet` within the Scala collections framework?

Comment: Tricky question. What it comes down to I guess is if your `MultiSet` is an `A => Int` or an `A => Boolean`. It is common to do `filter` like operations with sets and thus see it as an `exists` method. If your set should be an `A => Int` you would probably need to create a `MultiSetLike` trait that mimics `SetLike`. That way you could escape the `A => Boolean` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I would have to override some inherited methods like intersect because they would do the wrong things for multisets

I think you'll have to bite the bullet and do just that.

> Another problem with extending Set is that then I can't have MultiSet be an `A => Int`

Indeed, you cannot inherit twice the same trait (here `Function1`) with different type parameters. And actually in this case, this is not just an annoying technical limitation, but doing so would in fact not make much sense because when calling `apply` there would be no way to know which overload you want to call: `def apply( key: A ): Boolean` or `def apply( key: A ): Int`? You can't tell as the argument lists are the same.

However, what you could do is add an implicit conversion from `MultiSet[A]` to `A => Int`. This way, a `MultiSet` is treated by default as a `A => Boolean` (as any set), but can  be coerced to a `A => Int` when nedded (in particular it could be passed directly to a function expecting a `A => Int` function).

```
class MultiSet[A] ... {
  ...
  def count(elem: A): Int = counts.getOrElse( elem, 0 )
}
object MultiSet {
  ...
  implicit def toCountFunc[A]( ms: MultiSet[A] ): A => Int = { 
    (x: A) => ms.count( x )
  } 
}
```

Some test i the REPL:

```
scala> val ms = MultiSet("a" -> 2, "b" -> 5)
ms: MultiSet[String] = Set(a, a, b, b, b, b, b)
scala> ms("a")
res17: Boolean = true
scala> ms("c")
res18: Boolean = false

scala> def testExists( f: String => Boolean, keys: String *) {
     |   println( keys.map( f ).toList )
     | }
testExists: (f: String => Boolean, keys: String*)Unit
scala> testExists( ms, "a", "c" )
List(true, false)

scala> def testCounts( f: String => Int, keys: String *) {
     |   println( keys.map( f ).toList )
     | }
testCounts: (f: String => Int, keys: String*)Unit
scala> testCounts( ms, "a", "c" )
List(2, 0)
```

Comment: So if I still have to write `intersect` and an implicit conversion, maybe I shouldn't inherit from `Set` but should instead inherit from `Traversable` or something like that?

Comment: In any case you will have to implement `intersect`, so why not keep `Set` as a base trait, override `intersect` and be done with it? At least your collection will be a proper Set, which is the least you would expect from a MultiSet.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my worry was that there would be more methods on `Set` that I hadn't thought of that also do the wrong thing. But that probably just means I need to write more test cases. ;-)